# login and password Thingsboard/local installation

Tags: thingsboard

i have locally installed https://thingsboard.io/ but i can't find a proper login and password. I've tried to log with tenant/tenant but in vain. Help please!

Answer (score 4):

[From below mentioned link]

If you are using local ThingsBoard installation you can login to administration Web UI using default account:

Username: **tenant@thingsboard.org**
Password: **tenant**

Link: https://thingsboard.io/docs/getting-started-guides/helloworld/#login-as-a-tenant-administrator

Comment: System Administrator
Default system administrator account:

login - sysadmin@thingsboard.org.
password - sysadmin.
Demo Tenant
Default tenant administrator account:

login - tenant@thingsboard.org.
password - tenant.
Demo tenant customers:

Customer A users - customer@thingsboard.org or customerA@thingsboard.org.
Customer B users - customerB@thingsboard.org.
Customer C users - customerC@thingsboard.org.
all users have “customer” password.

From https://thingsboard.io/docs/samples/demo-account/

Comment: Thanks everyone for your response, @Andrew,@raevilman! Actually the sysadmin@thingsboard.org/sysadmin works just fine. unfortunately i didn't try this one. Thanks again!